# Django Admin : Class Media

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a class Media as follows

```
class helloAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = ['choice.js']
admin.site.register(hello,helloAdmin)
```

The staticfiles app prepends `STATIC_URL` to the media path. But I want `MEDIA_URL` to be prepended instead of `STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_URL` isn't empty. How can this be done?

Comment: Personally I can't see how you could do that, but is there a reason for this? Since, you know, MEDIA_URL is for user uploaded files and not for static media.

Comment: Can you tell me your `MEDIA_URL`, `MEDIA_ROOT`, `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL` so that I can help you better?

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve that with the following settings:

```
import os
CURRENT_PATH = os.path.abspath((os.path.dirname(__file__)))

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(CURRENT_PATH, 'uploads')

MEDIA_URL = '/site_media/'
```

#### urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
)
```

#### admin.py

```
class helloAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = ['/site_media/choice.js']
admin.site.register(hello,helloAdmin)
```

Using `MEDIA_URL` is not advised for serving static files. According to django documentation, `MEDIA_URL` will not be referred for media files, when `STATIC_URL` is **not empty**. Refer to [this part of documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/media/#paths-in-media-definitions).

So I recommend you to use the following settings:

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(CURRENT_PATH, 'media'),
)
```

#### admin.py

```
class helloAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = ['choice.js']
admin.site.register(hello,helloAdmin)
```